# How to make a statement unnecessary with replace() in insertion-sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I hope someone can help me out with this assignment. So we got this C++ algorithm by my professor:

```
template<class T> //Parameterized by the Type T
void insertion_sort(array<T>& A) //A is an array of Ts
//Permutes the elements of A into ascending sorted order
//The lower index bound of A is assumed to be 1
{ int n = A.size();
  for(int k=2; k<=n; k++)
  { T x = A[k];   //x is a a variable of type T
  //Insert x in the sorted sequence A[1], ..., A[k-1]
    int i = k-1;
    while (i>=1&&x<A[i])  //A[i] is evaluated only if i>=1
    { A[i+1]=A[i];
      i--;
    }
    A[i+1]=x;
  }
}
```

Ok. Now I have to use the function A.resize(0, n) between the lines 5 and 6 so that the statement "i>=1" in the while function becomes unnecessary. I understand that when this function is used the lower index bound of A becomes 0 instead of 1. But I do not see any use of that because I would still need that statement in the while. Does anyone have an idea?

I would be very grateful.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That will be quite a trick, since [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) does not have a resize method.

Comment: My professor said he uses the library called "Leda" for this function.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude `i>=1` condition, you can move the smallest array element into the first position before the main loop.
Now this element becomes "sentinel" and it's presence excludes run out of array range.

If it is strictly needed to use your `resize`, then just set the smallest possible value (look at [lowest](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/lowest)) to new element with 0-th index.

*We can not know about "magic" routines from some library*

Comment: But then it's not a sorting algorithm because I do not know where the smallest array element in the array is. A.resize(0, n) adds an additional unknown element at the beginning of the array without changing the indices of the other elements.

Comment: You can make the first traversal to find the smallest. If it is strictly needed to use your `resize`, then just set the **smallest possible value** (-infinity, -MAXINT, [lowest](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) etc) to new element with 0-th index.